# How to Count primitive operations of a while Loop

Tags: python, python-2.x

Counting only {+, -, *, /, //,%, >, <, ==,<=, >= } as basic operations, determine the exact number of basic operations that would be performed when the following code fragment is executed for the given values of n and t.

```
n = 5
t = 3
s = 0
i = 0
j = 0
x = n
while s < t:
    if x % 2 == 1:
        i = i + 1
    x = x // 2
    for k in xrange(n):
        s = s + 1
        j = j + i
print(j)
```

i Know the answer is 23 but i get 19 with this 6*n+1 equation

Comment: Can you explain a little more thoroughly what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: Also, please double-check your indentation. As is, this code will loop infinitely because you never update `s` or `t` in your `while` loop.

Comment: im trying to count the operations of the while loops excluding '='

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you describe how you came to your count. I attempted to do what you're describing and came up with 16.

Comment: ok i got 6*n+1 because its 6 operations in the while loop multiply by the number of time it loops with the condition of n and the +1 is for when the loop ends when condition is met

Comment: @Geddez Only the operations in the `for` loop are executed `n` times. The `while` loop only runs once, because after the first time through, `s == n`. Grab a pencil and paper and run through it manually (or put a bunch of print statements in the loop to watch the flow).

Comment: I think I see the issue... your initial post said `n = 5` and `t = 3`. Is that supposed to be the other way around? `t = 5` and `n = 3`? Because with that, I get 23 operations.

Comment: ah yes it is t=5 and n=3 can u use an equation to find it or u have to go thru manually

Comment: You'll need to go through manually unless you're able to port something like a_guest's solution below to python 2. The main problem is the line inside the `if` statement, which may or may not run depending on the value of `x` when you get there.

Comment: ok if t=7 and n=5 it would also be 30?

Comment: @Geddez Yes, it seems so.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a small wrapper class to register calls to the relevant methods (corresponding to `+`, `-`, `...`):

```
class Integer(int):
    n_ops = 0

def new_patch(name):
    def patch(self, other):
        Integer.n_ops += 1
        value = getattr(int, name)(self, other)
        if isinstance(value, int) and not (value is True or value is False):
            value = Integer(value)
        print(f'{repr(self)} {methods[name]} {repr(other)} -> {repr(value)}')
        return value
    patch.__name__ = name
    return patch

methods = {
    '__le__': '\u2264',
    '__lt__': '<',
    '__ge__': '\u2265',
    '__gt__': '>',
    '__eq__': '==',
    '__add__': '+',
    '__sub__': '-',
    '__mul__': '*',
    '__floordiv__': '//',
    '__mod__': '%',
}
for name in methods:
    setattr(Integer, name, new_patch(name))
```

Then using this wrapper class in place of the builtin integers we can count the operations:

```
n = 5
t = Integer(3)
s = Integer(0)
i = Integer(0)
j = Integer(0)
x = Integer(n)
while s < t:
    if x % 2 == 1:
        i = i + 1
    x = x // 2
    for k in range(n):
        s = s + 1
        j = j + i
print(f'j = {j}')
print(f'Number of operations: {Integer.n_ops}')
```

Which counts 16 operations:

```
0 < 3 -> True
5 % 2 -> 1
1 == 1 -> True
0 + 1 -> 1
5 // 2 -> 2
0 + 1 -> 1
0 + 1 -> 1
1 + 1 -> 2
1 + 1 -> 2
2 + 1 -> 3
2 + 1 -> 3
3 + 1 -> 4
3 + 1 -> 4
4 + 1 -> 5
4 + 1 -> 5
5 < 3 -> False
j = 5
Number of operations: 16
```

---

### More general version

Including more methods:

```
class Integer(int):
    n_ops = 0

def new_patch(name):
    def patch(self, *args):
        Integer.n_ops += 1
        value = getattr(int, name)(self, *args)
        if isinstance(value, int) and not (value is True or value is False):
            value = Integer(value)
        print(f'{name}({repr(self)}, {repr(args)}) -> {repr(value)}')
        return value
    patch.__name__ = name
    return patch

methods = [f'__{name}__' for name in ('le', 'lt', 'ge', 'gt', 'eq', 'ne', 'neg', 'pos', 'abs', 'invert')]
for name in ('add', 'sub', 'mul', 'truediv', 'floordiv', 'mod', 'divmod', 'pow', 'lshift', 'rshift', 'and', 'xor', 'or'):
    methods.extend((f'__{name}__', f'__r{name}__', f'__i{name}__'))

for name in methods:
    setattr(Integer, name, new_patch(name))
```

With output:

```
__lt__(0, (3,)) -> True
__mod__(5, (2,)) -> 1
__eq__(1, (1,)) -> True
__add__(0, (1,)) -> 1
__floordiv__(5, (2,)) -> 2
__add__(0, (1,)) -> 1
__add__(0, (1,)) -> 1
__add__(1, (1,)) -> 2
__add__(1, (1,)) -> 2
__add__(2, (1,)) -> 3
__add__(2, (1,)) -> 3
__add__(3, (1,)) -> 4
__add__(3, (1,)) -> 4
__add__(4, (1,)) -> 5
__add__(4, (1,)) -> 5
__lt__(5, (3,)) -> False
j = 5
Number of operations: 16
```